# close icon no white x on IE 11

Tags: css

https://plnkr.co/edit/SQWYTqV93dVw3WNnLSuT?p=preview

Will be hard to see but in the top right corner when I view this with Chrome it has the black circle with the white X, but in IE there is no white X. Any ideas why or how to get the white X to show up in IE?

```
.close-icon
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right:-5px;
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-width:3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:black;
    border-radius:100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%,  white 56%,transparent 56%, transparent 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%,  white 56%,transparent 56%, transparent 100%);
    background-color:black;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Comment: IE doesn't support `-webkit-linear-gradient`...

Comment: Does it support something similar that can give me a white X like that is?

Comment: Why don't you just render an "X" character or the times "⨉" character instead of using a hacky gradient?

Comment: I didn't know it was considered hacky to use a gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't support `-webkit-` prefixes, so it's ignoring your gradient and thus isn't rendering. A better solution would be to omit the gradient completely and use explicit symbols, e.g.,

```css
.close {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.close::before {
  content: '×';
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="close"></div>
```